# Sudden too many errors: methods are undefined

Tags: simulation, anylogic

My DES model was working well till I've added a new function (just like many others added before) and the model gave me all these error messages:

[image]

I wonder what do these messages mean and what made all of them appear suddenly. I was running the model just before it without any errors. Is there a way I could get my model back? :)

Thank you.

Edit 1:
Here is the newly created function: [Newly created function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLYIx.jpg)

Given that I've ignored it, and made all the callings of it as comments, then the errors were still appearing. I've closed this model version and opened a backup then created the same function and the whole scenario happened again with the same 94 errors.

Is there something I need to change in the function itself?
The function checks the number of agents in certain parts of the model to stop delay blocks accordingly. That's done by adding variables that increment on exiting of agents and get the difference between them.

Comment: Getting your old model back: That’s called “backup”, where you make a copy of the last working model. Or better, you use a source code control system that will store all versions of the model you ever used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically this is caused by a syntax error in the new function that you created. See if you ignore this and then compile if it gets fixed.

Most of the time the compiler is smart enough to show you the error, but often if you replace a `{` with `[` or you leave out a `{` the compiler get very confused and gives you 100s of errors.

If yous still cant find the issue maybe paste the code of your new function in the question.

Comment: Thank you. I've ignored the function but the same errors are still appearing. I added the code to the question.

Comment: If you say you started from a backup and then inserted the functional gain and get the same errors some part in the function is broken - do it step by step and building your model after every small step until you find it... try pasting your function code in the question as well (formatted as code of course)

Comment: I made what you say about checking the function and it proved the function to be right. So I investigated around and found that the cause of the errors was that I made my old code lines, which are now replaced by calling my new function, into a comment block using only "/*" at the beginning of the block and I missed adding "*/" at the end. I repeated this mistake 4 times and they yielded these 94 errors :)

Now it's solved. Good to know that the compiler may get that confused. It's not only me at least!

Comment: Happens to the best of us! ( or so I have heard ;-) ) That is where version control software like Git makes your life easier as you can see line by line what you changed from your previous commit and (easily?) spot issues